# Device name changes without any indication resulted of massive data copying

Tags: file-copy, ntfs, unmounting

I have Linux machine with two external ntfs-formatted hard drives. One of the drives contains data, the other one is supposed to be a back-up.

I run `Rsync` to copy data from the first drive to the second one. It was running for the first time and the net volume of data was about 1 TB. It had happily copied about a quarter of it. And at that point strange things started to happen.

The back-up-to-be drive dismounted for no reason. I mounted it back and noticed that its name changed from `sdc1` to `sde1` (I use device ID to mount drives, so I noticed it accidentally). All right, I re-launched `Rsync` that started to copy the rest, only to find the drive dismounted again without any apparent reason in a couple of minutes! `Gparted` showed that it became `sdf1`. One more iteration and we came to... you guessed it, `sdg1`.

That makes me wondering what would happen upon reaching `sdz1`. But more important question is what is going on here (defective drive is a tempting, albeit very frustrating hypothesis, but, actually, it is a brand new one bought a few days ago...)?

Comment: The next device after `/dev/sdz` is `/dev/sdaa`. You can have up to 16 * 1048576 `sd` devices on a system, 16 major numbers and 1048576 minor numbers. As for the device disconnecting you should see messages in `dmesg` saying what happened.

Comment: FYI, I have systems with `/dev/sdaa` though `/dev/sddp` available. I assume that after `/dev/sdzz` you'll wind up with `/dev/sdaaa` but I'm having a hard time imagining the physical configuration to require this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the drive may be faulty, or perhaps has a bad cable/connector. If it was just recently bought, a warranty replacement should be possible.

Another possibility is that the external drive is receiving borderline insufficient power: at times of high workload, the lack of power could cause the drive to "drop off" and be re-detected.

Comment: Thank you. The first option is on the table surely, but thorough scanning of the drive in Linux and Windows (including surface scanning) did not reveal any thing wrong. That would be kind of difficult to prove it to be faulty (and judging by scan results the drive looks fine to me). The second possible reason... well, it did not occur to me. You might be right. Difficult to work it around, though.

Comment: If the external drive is connected with USB with no power supply of its own, you might want to try adding a USB hub that has its own power supply in between the computer and the external drive. That should allow the drive to draw more power from the hub's supply instead of from the computer's USB port.

Answer (score 0):

I may have resolved (or worked around) my problem by plugging the drive to the Windows computer we have at home and launching copying process from there. Now the data are being copied to the back-up from the first drive (which ist still plugged to the Linux computer) over LAN. Kind of strange that network solution proves to be more robust rather than the one where the drives are plugged to the same computer, but apparently, this is how it is (possibly, because of the power issues hypothesized above).

On the second thought, is it really weird that Windows is more stable than Linux when it comes to handling NTFS-formatted drives?